# Как задать параметры дочерней функции внутри главной функции?

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть функция:

```
def filter_size(row, limit=20):
    if (row['y']==1) & (row['s']>limit) & (row['step_vol']>limit):
        val = 1
    else:
        val = 0
    return val
```

Как видите, в этой функции есть 2 параметра: `row`, `limit`
Функцию filter_size, я использую внутри  другой функции:

```
def get_target_size(data, predict_step = 5, trades = 5):
    """
        data - dataset for preprocessing
        predict_step - the number of trades in the future where we want to predict the movement
        trades - the number of trades in the past we use for prediction
        return: X, y - attributes and target for models 
    """
    data['step'] = data['p'].shift(predict_step)
    data['step_vol'] = data['s'].shift(predict_step)
    data['step-1'] = data['p'].shift(predict_step+1)
    for i in range(1, trades+1):
        data[i] = data['step-1'].pct_change(i)
    data.dropna(inplace = True) 
    data['y'] = data['p'] - data['step']
    data['y'] = data['y'].apply(lambda s: 1 if s > 0 else 0)
    data['y'] = data.apply(filter_size, axis=1)
    y = data['y']
    y = y[:-trades]
    X = data.drop(['p', 'step', 'step-1', 'y', 'step_vol'], axis=1)
    X = X[:-trades]
    print('Classes distribution:')
    print(data['y'].value_counts())
    print('X shape: {}'.format(X.shape))
    print('y shape: {}'.format(y.shape))

    return X, y
```

Как я могу изменять параметры первой функции `filter_size` (скажем, я хочу задать `limit=50`) при вызове второй функции `get_target_size`?

Сейчас мне приходтся каждый раз корректировать функцию `filter_size`, когда я хочу изменить `limit`, что не очень удобно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_target_size(data, predict_step=5, trades=5, limit=50):
    ...
    data['y'] = data.apply(filter_size, limit=limit, axis=1)
    ...
```